# How to train a GMM using different size datasets in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gmm

I'm trying to use a GMM to generate synthetic data based on 28 datasets of different size. The datasets consist in a list of coordinates (x, y, z) of the position of certain molecules I'm trying to replicate synthetically. For instance, suppose I have the following three datasets in the form of numpy arrays (the real datasets contains hundreds or thousands of coordinates):

```
dataset1 = array([[ -23.40615192, -105.30347846,  106.5562609 ],
   [ -47.24327393, -122.24249306,  105.13437965],
   [ -38.14460785,  -93.42933431,   96.78474773],
   [ -36.72412585, -106.34904917,   88.97037884]])

dataset2 = array([[ -29.60147729,  -90.73071122,  113.1567724 ],
   [ -31.76138045,  -93.35949818,  133.9334376 ],
   [ -16.31718164,  -91.41650939,  100.26570896]])

dataset3 = array([[ 111.799484,  -86.1     ,   14.38    ],
   [  97.88    ,  -93.036994,   14.38    ],
   [  76.35    ,  -80.89    ,   12.826868],
   [  49.26    ,  -77.827499,   16.88    ],
   [  31.561942,  -84.15    ,   16.88    ],
   [  -3.6     , -151.01    ,   17.070828],
   [  70.8     ,  -60.99    ,   13.876267],
   [  84.996985,  -61.64    ,   18.93    ],
   [  75.612867,  -47.94    ,   18.93    ],
   [  53.667344,  -61.31    ,   18.93    ]])
```

I have already generated synthetic data based on ONE dataset using the `[GaussianMixture][1]` function from sklearn as follows:

```
from sklearn import mixture    
model = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=50, covariance_type='full').fit(dataset1)
syntheticdata = model.sample(2000)
```

It works pretty well but I'd like to generate a single model using all the datasets (which are of different sizes) at once. Is this possible?

Comment: I assume that the three components should not share the same weights across the datasets, right ?

Comment: @WholeBrain I'm not sure about that honestly. Imagine I want to generate 8 synthetic (x, y, z) coordinates;  should dataset3 be given a greater weight given that the other two datasets are smaller? That's what confuses me (in addition to how to implement it in python).

Comment: My question was even more trivial. Are your samples sharing the same distribution across datasets, or do you assume each dataset has its own distribution ? In other words, are your datasets representing similar populations or different ones, probabilistically speaking ? If the answer is that they share the same distribution, then you would simply concatenate all datasets along the first axis. Otherwise, then you want a model that must have distincts sets of weights trained on distinct datasets. Those two combined properties kinda defeat the purpose of having a single model.

Comment: I get it now. All the datasets were obtained following the same protocol, but from different experiments, so currently I'm assuming all the datasets share the same distribution (although I should verify this). I'll concatenate all the datasets as you suggested. Thanks for your help!